# Проблемка с битриксом на Open server

Tags: битрикс

Устанавливаю битрикс на Open server и выскакивает ошибка:

> Версия веб-сервера не выяснен

Как с этим справиться?

Comment: В php.ini параметры `mbstring.func_overload` и `mbstring.internal_encoding` установили в нужные значения?

Comment: Было бы понятнее, если бы кто-нибудь сказал: почему скрипт битрикса не может определить версию веб-сервера (в случае openserver). Сам битрикс тупо молчит: купите, и мы всё настроим...

Answer (score 2):

Как уже писали про настройки mbstring
Так же советую глянуть настройки сервера и выставить в модулях:
HTTP: Apache-2.4
PHP: PHP-5.6
MySQL: MySQL-5.6

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего это связано с настройками `mbstring`. Установите в `php.ini`:

```
mbstring.func_overload 2
mbstring.internal_encoding utf-8
```

Comment: Где найти php.ini укажить пункт к файлу

Comment: В контекстном меню есть открытие php.ini который используется в настоящий момент.

Answer (score 0):

Характеристика версии веб-сервера не критична для успешной установки Битрикс (я ставлю пробную версию). В остальном, очень хорошо описано [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3WT3_FJGf0). В видео рассмотрено, как сделать общую настройку и "мульти"-настройку для доменов Битрикс отдельно и для других отдельно. У меня на Apache 2.4 - PHP 7.3 все работает, при чем даже не прописывал пути к доменам вручную. УДАЛИТЕ (если не заработает как на видео) символ *